# How to know the location of max or min value of a matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix, location

I have a (n*p), but for simplicity, I will use a 5*2 matrix to ask questions,

suppose I have a matrix A

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 5, 2)
```

I can find max. and min. value by using `which.max(A)` and `which.min(A)`.

The question is how to return a value that can tell the location of this max value of the matrix. like the value of `which.max(A)`, 10, into location (5,2).

and also, can i get the answer in to coordinate?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `which()` with the option `arr.ind=TRUE`:

```
> which(A==max(A), arr.ind=T)
#     row col
#[1,]   5   2
```

The coordinates (row and column numbers) can be stored in a vector, like so

```
xy <- as.vector(which(A==max(A), arr.ind=T))
> xy
#[1] 5 2
> xy[1]
# 5
> xy[2]
#[1] 2
```

Comment: why answering when it's a duplicate? Search for it first ;)

Comment: can i change it into coordinate like (5,2)?